# SQL variable type for table id

Tags: mysql, database, variables, primary-key, variable-length

Usually when I need an ID for a database table, I just declare it as **UNSIGNED INT**, 
but what is the maximum value for this kind of ID? How can I know it? I'm using mysql server, but i think it would be useful to get an answer for all platforms.
If I'm doing wrong, what kind of id *should* be used  instead?

Comment: Didn't you find the range in the MySQL doc?

Comment: Well i COULD do that, but here I also ask for a practical advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL max value in UNSIGNED INT, can be stored is 4294967295.

Have a look at [Integer Storage in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)